# Error on building Boost of Point cloud library from source on Windows

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library

When I built Boost for Point Cloud Library from source on windows 32bit MSVC 2010 - boost  1.55.0 download from (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/). When using CMAke 3.4.0 for building, it has errors:

```
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL/PCL_dependencies/boost_1_55_0/build/CMakeCache.txt.tmp
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL/PCL_dependencies/boost_1_55_0" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. C:/Program Files (x86)/PCL/PCL_dependencies/boost_1_55_0/build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the directory (probably is the install directory) to something different than  C:/Program Files (x86) , make sure you use a directory where it's possible to write without being administrator